# NSString initWithContentsOfURL problems

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am updating an iOS app to be a good boy and clean out some deprecated methods. I have been using `NSString initWithContentsOfURL` and I am trying to implement the new version `initWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:`.

I have used the following in my view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://myurl.com/directory/file.txt"];
    NSError *error;
    NSStringEncoding *encoding = NULL;
    NSString *tryString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                 usedEncoding:encoding
                                                        error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"string:%@", tryString);
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

But I keep getting a thread break at the `error:NULL` point. I have tried `error:nil` and using a pointer to the predefined error object as `nil` or `NULL` but same thing happens. Has anyone any ideas or tips.

Comment: Check the documentation, the method you're using returns the encoding by reference. You are probably looking for this one instead - `(id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error` and use NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSStringEncoding encoding = 0;

NSString *tryString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                 usedEncoding:&encoding
                                                        error:&error];
```

Comment: still getting the thread break at the NSError line. Thanks Monolo

Comment: Ahhh!! *error pointer was in use elsewhere!! All working now. Many thanks to all. Both code snippets work great. Thanks chaps.

Answer (score 1):

Both the error and encoding should be pass like this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSStringEncoding encoding = nil;

NSString *tryString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                 usedEncoding:&encoding
                                                        error:&error];
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this by copying your code and now get the thread break at NSError *error = nil; But thanks. Maybe there is something elsewhere.

Comment: This is not the correct approach. `encoding` should not be a pointer.

Comment: Sorry maddy. I am new to obj-c and ios. Can you be more specific.

Comment: @user1548284 That comment was to Jacky Boy. The code in the answer you accepted is correct. The code in this answer is not. Notice the difference in how `encoding` is declared and used in the two answers.

Comment: I made a change last night, apparently wasn't editted. Made the change now. Thanks @rmaddy.